# Why entity objects are not equal if I get one of that object with another fetched object that has collection elements although they should be?

Tags: java, hibernate, set, equals, hashcode

I have 3 entity clasess that have relationships on each others

TestClassParent :

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "email")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class TestClassParent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;
}
```

TestClassChild :

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class TestClassChild extends TestClassParent{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_collection_id")
    private TestChildCollection testChildCollection;
}
```

TestChildCollection :

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of ="id")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestChildCollection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "testChildCollection",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TestClassChild> testClassChildSet;
}
```

Currently my database look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Relationships :

[image]

Equalitiy of objects is done by comparing their email

I have code for testing this case:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DemoApplication {
    private final TestClassChildRepository testClassRepository;
    private final TestChildCollectionRepository testChildCollectionRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
        return args -> {
            TestClassChild testClassChild = testClassRepository.findById(1L).get();
            TestClassChild testClass1 = new TestClassChild();
            testClass1.setId(testClassChild.getId());
            testClass1.setEmail(new String("newTestEmail2"));
            System.out.println(testClass1.equals(testClassChild));
        };
    }

}
```

And I get false for comparing these objects

Result is : [image]

I looked for debug and saw that, first instance has hashcode in email, and another one doesn't
First one:

[image]

Second one:

[image]

Comment: Field `testChildCollection` in `TestClassChild` class  is used in equals() method, it seems you need `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)` instead of `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)`. BTW I do believe it is not a good idea to override equals/hashCode methods in this way, think about following: technically JPA record represents DB row, do equal records must point to the same row or not?

Answer (score 0):

`testClassRepository.findById(1L).get();` returns an object with `testChildCollection`. When you generate a new `TestClassChild` you set id and email, but not the collection, but in your example Lombok also uses the `testChildCollection` to calculate equals/hashCode.

When using inheritance I usually try to avoid using `@Data`, because it's easy to loose track of how the equals/hashCode are actually generated.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true) // Only if you really need a toString implementation that also prints your collection.
public class TestClassChild extends TestClassParent
```

Will do the same just without the hashCode/equals generation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `TestClassChild` `equals()` method also include a check for its `testChildCollection` property. The variable `testClassChild` has such property as not null, but `testClass1` has it as null. Hence the call `testClass1.equals(testClassChild)` will always be `false`.

If you only want to rely on the superclass `equals()` implementation, then you will have to exclude `testClassChild` as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class TestClassChild extends TestClassParent{

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_collection_id")
    private TestChildCollection testChildCollection;
}
```